# Function calling itself as a goroutine, is this dangerous?

Tags: go, recursion

I'm not sure is this will generate a leak. I'm assuming that, since I'm returning the function `GetFile` after launching the go routine its probably ok. But I'm not sure if it could be a problem, eg. no file is found in a long time.

```
func (p *MyStruct) Launch() {
   go p.Generate()
}

func (p *MyStruct) Generate() {
    file := p.GetFile()
    if file == "" {
         return
    }

    // Do stuff with the file
}

func (p *MyStruct) GetFile() string {
    // Get file
    *p.SyncChan <- id
    fileToProcess, err := tools.ReserveFile(p.Name, id, p.BufferIndex)
    <- *p.SyncChan

    if fileToProcess == "" {
        time.Sleep(time.Minute * 6)
        go p.Generate()
        return ""
    }
    return fileToProcess
}
```

Comment: No the recursion is not the problem. The thing is, when you start a goroutine you should always think about the end of the goroutine. Also there is no benefit in creating a new goroutine, why not just use a normal recursion?

Comment: I'm doing it this way because it feels cleaner to me (I could be wrong of course hehe). Also because of the way the app is built I don't need to track the goroutines, it's ok if they exit on their own.

Comment: What is clearer when you write `p.Generate()` instead of `go p.Generate()`?

Comment: You are using `*MyStruct`. Passing this pointer around different goroutines can create data races and really bad bugs. Your code at all is hard to read. The thing `GetFile()` does is: try every 6 minutes to reaserve a file until you can reserve it. If you use a for loop your code will be much easear to understand.

Comment: Yeah that is true, the purpose of doing it this way is so I can at any point during the execution go back to the start of the Generate method, it's not obvious with this snippet because is quite simple, but imagine that inside the GetFile there are several stages, at any point I would be able to go back to the start of Generate
I'm wondering also if launching a go routine sort of detaches itself from the parent function, because a normal recursive call will fill the stack trace maybe? that's the sort of stuff I'm not sure how to handle in go

Comment: @FranciscoRangel Go proverb: [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://youtu.be/cN_DpYBzKso). Furthermore, if a deeper nested iteration might be executed first, you might get funky results. I would put the first call to a recursive function into a groutine under certain circumstances. But since for example a http.Handler is called as a groutine anyway, this would not help (much, presumably, you get the idea.).